# Only select the first row from another joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

`Labs`  
`==========`
`LabID`
`==========`

`1`

`Messages`  
`==========`
`Message`
`==========`

`Hello world`

`Hello world 2`

I want to join the two tables so the output becomes:

`=== Lab ID === Messages ===`

```
 1 Hello World
```

If I do

`select * from Labs l inner join Messages m on l.LabID = m.LabID`

It prints out the first ID twice because there are two messages in that table. I only want to select the first message.
I tried adding top 1 but that doesn't do anything. I'm really new to SQL.

Comment: You need some way to differentiate between the 2 rows in the second table, and to select only one of them?

Comment: yes I can try that

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the entire content of those tables?

Comment: You must have LabID as a column in Messages, what other columns do you have, is there a date/time column that you could grab either the latest or earliest message?

Comment: yes there is a labid column in messages and a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the latest message per lab. One option uses a lateral join. Assuming that table `messages` has a foreign key column called `labid` that refers to `labs`, and a column called `id` that can be used to order the rows, you would phrase this as:

```
select l.*, m.mesage
from labs l 
cross apply (
    select top (1) * from messages m where m.labid = l.labid order by m.id desc
) m
```

If you want to allow labs that have no messages, use `outer apply` instead.

Another option is `row_number()`:

```
select l.*, m.mesage
from labs l 
inner join (
    select m.*, row_number() over(partition by labid order by id desc) rn
    from messages m
) m on m.labid = l.labid and m.rn = 1
```